# Are there any data for GIS for Substations?

Tags: geospatial, data, gas

I am working on a project and review each quad using the USGS Topos and need the data for Substation that has the points.  I could not find it .  Location is in Colorado. This is for my field crew workers that will be using for Field Maps or apps in the field

Comment: Just to be clear, by "substation" do you mean electric system facilities to transform voltage between high and low? Why the "gas" tag?

Comment: @NicolasRaoul  yes, when I was working on a map and it said on it however, if they no longer using it then I think they are using the transmission lines. I have been searching for it but no luck.  Gas because I have seen it both in gas and electronic transmissions but I dont know if gas is exist.